# Need to append PS command Get-NetIPAddress to display InterfaceAlias AND IPv4 Address only

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, microsoft

This is my first post here, so apologies if I've posted this in an incorrect area, if that's even a thing here. Could not find a similar question with this exact scenario, so here goes.

I am writing a BadUSB script for use with my Flipper Zero to email me all active IP addresses with adapter names. I have it working, it works great, however I am having a hard time understanding how I need to append the `Get-NetIPAddress` command to list `InterfaceAlias` followed by IPv4 Addresses ONLY. I can get it to work with one or the other, but I am not familiar enough with this specific command to know where to go from here. No help on the typical powershell user communities.

Currently trying these:

```
(Get-NetIPAddress | where-object {$_.addressfamily -eq 'ipv4'}).interfacealias

(Get-NetIPAddress | where-object {$_.addressfamily -eq 'ipv4'}).ipaddress
```

Need a way to combine these two to output both parameters.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1758294/edit) your question and post text input/output from your code instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets and pipe the output to the `SELECT-OBJECT` like the following:

```ps
Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"} | select InterfaceAlias, IPAddress
```

Comment: Reddy, thank you. Everything I was finding made it seem like I needed to keep the ( ) in place, but this makes more sense. I appreciate the quick reply and also edited my post to include the code instead of just the image, as suggested. Thank you

Comment: @aberg94 Please mark the answer as solved if your question has been answered. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)